# Android 11- Location One-Time Permission, how to know if this was selected by the user

Tags: android, android-11

In Android 11, with the new permission grant logic for one-time permission request. How can we know when "Only this time" Location was selected and not the "While app in use".

Is there a way to distinguish the two granted permissions at runtime programmatically.

Comment: I don't think so . One time permission is Session based and it will work as Allowed permission for this session only. There is not much difference than this  So when the session ends system will pop up permission dialog again . PS i haven't explored android 11 in depth yet ..